# Default style for layer group

Tags: qgis

I have about 20 different layers in my QGIS projects, all of which have the same properties.  I have been setting the properties as I create each layer, but that is time-consuming and error-prone.

Is it possible to set a properties default style for all the layers in a layer group?

Comment: Have you already tried to copy the style of one layer and paste it to the group?

Comment: You can save/load and copy/paste styles see https://www.packtpub.com/books/content/style-management-qgis

Answer (score 2):

You can use [MultiQml](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/multiqml/) to assign the same style to selected layers or all layers in the table of content. The plugin can apply the same style to vector layers as well as to raster layers. You need first to save the style as `.qml` file, then apply the style that you saved to the a group of layers that you want.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1 - Install the Plugin : **MultiQml**

[image]

2 - Save the Qml **Style**

[image]

3 - **Aplly** the style to the group layer

[image]